# error: 'log2' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, c++11, macports, gcc5

I'm not sure what I am seeing here. The test results below are from an old PowerMac G5 running OS X 10.5.8. Its still around for testing under the big-endian PowerPC cpu. The compiler is GCC 5.4, and its provided by MacPorts.

The test program is below. Compiling it results in an error ***`error: 'log2' is not a member of 'std'`***.

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <cmath>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double d = std::log2(2.3456789f);
    return 0;
}
```

According to [Is std::log2() an extension or C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22388630), `std::log2` should be available.

Why is the program failing to compile?

---

```
$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-5 --version
g++-mp-5 (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-5 -std=c++11 test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cxx:4:16: error: 'log2' is not a member of 'std'
     double d = std::log2(2.3456789f);
                ^
test.cxx:4:16: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:26:0,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/cmath:44,
                 from test.cxx:1:
/usr/include/architecture/ppc/math.h:431:15: note:   'log2'
 extern double log2( double );
               ^
```

---

This may be related because of the old hardware: [C++11 cmath functions not in std namespace for android NDK w/gcc-4.8 or clang 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22922961). I realize Android is a different platform.

---

Now open in the MacPorts issue tracker: [Issue 53226: PowerMac, GCC 5.4 and "error: 'std::log2' has not been declared"](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/53226).

Now open in the GCC issue tracker: [Issue 79017: Old PowerMac G5, MacPorts GCC 5.4, C++11 and "std::log2 has not been declared"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79017)

Comment: Given you are on Mac, please ensure you are not using the 4.2 headers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Does *`... from /opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/cmath`* indicate its using the expected header?

Comment: Just FYI, I tried in OSX 10.11.4 (Intel i7) both with g++-6 (installed via Homebrew) and clang++ and it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: It does indicate that the correct header is picked up by the compiler (potentially too late). Your setup is somehow botched. I'm not an Apple guy myself though, so I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Thanks. I was thinking it was a bad interaction with GCC or the port. Let me get the MacPort folks in the loop.

Comment: @jww Yes, for older versions of gcc or in some other platforms this has been seen: https://github.com/sharebrained/portapack-hackrf/issues/76  
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html  
Of course you could always use the C header as suggested by your compiler (of course after you checked the setup is ok): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733413/error-log2-is-not-a-member-of-std

Comment: Thanks @fedepad. The program above is the MCVE to ask the question. In real life, this is Jack Lloyd's [Botan Library](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/workfactor.cpp), which is a C++11 TLS library. I think I should probably ask the MacPorts and GCC folks for help with getting things back on-course rather than asking Jack to patch the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the program failing to compile?

The GCC report at [Issue 79017: Old PowerMac G5, MacPorts GCC 5.4, C++11 and "std::log2 has not been declared"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79017) got some good comments from the GCC devs.

According to [Jonathan Wakely and the results of the program below](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79017#c2):

> ```
> test.cxx:53:21: error: 'llrint' was not declared in this scope
> llrint(0.0);
>
> test.cxx:54:23: error: 'llrintf' was not declared in this scope
> llrintf(0.0f);
>
> test.cxx:55:23: error: 'llrintl' was not declared in this scope
> llrintl(0.0l);
>
> test.cxx:56:22: error: 'llround' was not declared in this scope
> llround(0.0);
>
> test.cxx:57:24: error: 'llroundf' was not declared in this scope
> llroundf(0.0f);
>
> test.cxx:58:24: error: 'llroundl' was not declared in this scope
> llroundl(0.0l);
> ```
>
> Because these six functions are missing we treat all C99 math
>   functions as missing. We could split the checks into two pieces, so we
>   check for these separately, which would allow the rest of the C99 math
>   library to be imported into namespace std.

---

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
          typedef double_t  my_double_t;
          typedef float_t   my_float_t;
          acosh(0.0);
          acoshf(0.0f);
          acoshl(0.0l);
          asinh(0.0);
          asinhf(0.0f);
          asinhl(0.0l);
          atanh(0.0);
          atanhf(0.0f);
          atanhl(0.0l);
          cbrt(0.0);
          cbrtf(0.0f);
          cbrtl(0.0l);
          copysign(0.0, 0.0);
          copysignf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          copysignl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          erf(0.0);
          erff(0.0f);
          erfl(0.0l);
          erfc(0.0);
          erfcf(0.0f);
          erfcl(0.0l);
          exp2(0.0);
          exp2f(0.0f);
          exp2l(0.0l);
          expm1(0.0);
          expm1f(0.0f);
          expm1l(0.0l);
          fdim(0.0, 0.0);
          fdimf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          fdiml(0.0l, 0.0l);
          fma(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
          fmaf(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          fmal(0.0l, 0.0l, 0.0l);
          fmax(0.0, 0.0);
          fmaxf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          fmaxl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          fmin(0.0, 0.0);
          fminf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          fminl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          hypot(0.0, 0.0);
          hypotf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          hypotl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          ilogb(0.0);
          ilogbf(0.0f);
          ilogbl(0.0l);
          lgamma(0.0);
          lgammaf(0.0f);
          lgammal(0.0l);
          llrint(0.0);
          llrintf(0.0f);
          llrintl(0.0l);
          llround(0.0);
          llroundf(0.0f);
          llroundl(0.0l);
          log1p(0.0);
          log1pf(0.0f);
          log1pl(0.0l);
          log2(0.0);
          log2f(0.0f);
          log2l(0.0l);
          logb(0.0);
          logbf(0.0f);
          logbl(0.0l);
          lrint(0.0);
          lrintf(0.0f);
          lrintl(0.0l);
          lround(0.0);
          lroundf(0.0f);
          lroundl(0.0l);
          nan(0);
          nanf(0);
          nanl(0);
          nearbyint(0.0);
          nearbyintf(0.0f);
          nearbyintl(0.0l);
          nextafter(0.0, 0.0);
          nextafterf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          nextafterl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          nexttoward(0.0, 0.0);
          nexttowardf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          nexttowardl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          remainder(0.0, 0.0);
          remainderf(0.0f, 0.0f);
          remainderl(0.0l, 0.0l);
          remquo(0.0, 0.0, 0);
          remquof(0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
          remquol(0.0l, 0.0l, 0);
          rint(0.0);
          rintf(0.0f);
          rintl(0.0l);
          round(0.0);
          roundf(0.0f);
          roundl(0.0l);
          scalbln(0.0, 0l);
          scalblnf(0.0f, 0l);
          scalblnl(0.0l, 0l);
          scalbn(0.0, 0);
          scalbnf(0.0f, 0);
          scalbnl(0.0l, 0);
          tgamma(0.0);
          tgammaf(0.0f);
          tgammal(0.0l);
          trunc(0.0);
          truncf(0.0f);
          truncl(0.0l);
          return 0;
}
```